# Efficient Replacement of Double-Byte Numerals to Single-Byte Numerals

Tags: regex, string, replace, double-byte

I am currently working on a website that is for Japan and by default, their keyboards use double-byte numerals (\uFF10-\uFF19) and this is causing an issue with validation as well as down the flow when we pass the data on to other services.  I am writing a function that replaces the double-byte with single-byte (\u0030-\u0039) before submission.

Currently, my plan was to use a lookup table and swap out number for number but feel this is inefficient when looping over a dozen inputs.  I'm confident their is a more efficient method that one of you RegEx gurus can come up with.

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really just a transliteration problem; and what you're replacing, and what you're replacing it with, is all contiguous.  So this will work:

```
function replaceFullWidthNumerals(s) {
  return s.replace( /[\uFF10-\uFF19]/g,
    function(m){
      return String.fromCharCode( m.charCodeAt() - 0xFEE0 );
    }
  );
}
```